# what is the equivalent for php appned to a string in python

Tags: python, php, migration, append

I am migrating php code into Python. My data is saved in `queryResults` variable. And looks like this:

```
OrderedDict([('totalSize', 44), ('done', True), ('records', [OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'Opportunity'), ('url', '/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Opportunity/0060z0000226XdJAAU')]))
```

As far as I understood the following php code creates an empty variable - output and appends the `queryResults` records in output variable. Then it parsed it with `parse_csv` function.

```
$output = "";

foreach ($queryResults as $line => $row) {
  $output .= $row;
}

$arr = parse_csv($output);
$newarr = array();
$keys = array();
$cnt = 0;
```

How would I do the same with Python? I have tried:

```
output = ""

for item in queryResults:
    output.append(item)
print(output)
```

Error message is: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'`

Answer (score 2):

Python strings are immutable, so you can't `append` them as you can lists. However, you can make a new string that is a concatenation of two strings:

```
output += item
```

Or you could just skip the loop and `join` them:

```
output = ''.join(queryResults)
```

Answer (score 0):

`append()` is a function of python lists.

Try to define output as a list: `output = []`

Comment: I did try it and the output is not what I expect this to be. It returns the first three values and that's it. The code in PhP then parse the output. With a list that returns three values there is nothing to parse...

Comment: Could you share the desired output to your question?